# AttributeError: module 'keras.src.backend' has no attribute 'floatx' When compiling a neural network for sentiment analysis

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import layers

# set the embedding dimension
embedding_dim = 100

# create the model
model = Sequential([
    layers.Embedding(max_words, embedding_dim, input_length=max_length),
    layers.LSTM(64),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

# compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# print the model summary
print(model.summary())
```

I tried to compile the model above in VSCode with Jupyter Notebook (.ipynb) but ran into the following error:

AttributeError: module 'keras.src.backend' has no attribute 'floatx'

Initially, I managed to compile the model with no problems, but caused VScode to crash when fitting the model. After reloading VSCode, I'm getting this error.

To explain the context, I'm trying to build a really basic NLP model to classify Amazon reviews based on sentiment. I'm also on Python 3.11 and Tensorflow version 2.15

At first I tried the following:

```
import keras.backend as K
K.set_floatx('float32')
```

But I got the same error. Then I tried reseting VSCode and running the notebook again but still I'm getting the same error?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question. I restarted my desktop and ran everything again. On the 2nd restart, it managed to compile without problems.